# No ordena un objeto con lambda (Java 8)

Tags: jpa, java-8, lambda

Estoy realizando una consulta de una tabla como objeto para insertarlo en otra tabla. Ordenando con lambda el codigo_alumno. Hice una prueba de concepto con dos valores enteros y si funcionó, pero cuando lo realizo con 2 valores String no me los ordena.

```
public void agregarDatos() {

    AlumnosMaeBean prueba = new AlumnosMaeBean();
    List<SisAlumnosMae> alumnoMaeList = prueba.consultaTodoMae();

    /*Ordenamos la lista por codigo alumno*/

    alumnoMaeList.sort((SisAlumnosMae h1, SisAlumnosMae h2) -> Integer.parseInt(h1.getCodigoAlumno()) - Integer.parseInt(h2.getCodigoAlumno()));

    /*agregamos a la tabla Sis_Alumnos_idx*/
    try {
        for (SisAlumnosMae mae : alumnoMaeList) {
            SisAlumnosIdx alumnoIdx = new SisAlumnosIdx();
            admin.getTransaction().begin();
            alumnoIdx.setCodigoAlumno(mae.getCodigoAlumno());
            alumnoIdx.setNombre(mae.getNombre());
            alumnoIdx.setApellido(mae.getApellido());
            alumnoIdx.setEdad(mae.getEdad());
            alumnoIdx.setSemestre(mae.getSemestre());
            alumnoIdx.setSexo(mae.getSexo());
            alumnoIdx.setEstadoAlumno(mae.getEstadoAlumno());
            alumnoIdx.setSecuenciaAlumno(mae.getSecuenciaAlumno());
            admin.persist(alumnoIdx);
            admin.merge(alumnoIdx);
            admin.getTransaction().commit();

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hola. ¿Puedes poner la salida donde aprecias que no esta ordenado?

Comment: @AlvaroC. Listo. Son las tablas de postgresql, y puedes ver que siguen igual. Si sirve de algo estoy usando JPA, uso entidades como tablas.

Comment: En la pregunta no se entiende si quieres ordenar por código o por otro campo del tipo `String`??? Y, si son datos de una tabla, ¿por qué no ordenas en el `SELECT`?

Comment: Prueba esto, para ordenar por el nombre, dando por supuesto que tu objeto `SisAlumnosMae` tiene un método `getNombre`... **`alumnoMaeList.sort(Comparator.comparing(SisAlumnosMae::getNombre));`** O bien, puedes probar así: **`alumnoMaeList.sort(Comparator.comparing(a -> a.getNombre));`**

Comment: @A.Cedano Claro, lo que quiero es ordenar por el codigo_alumno. El problema con el `SELECT`, es que me lo ordena de la siguiente manera: **1, 10, 15, 2. 20,25,3...** y asi sigue. Por ser String.

Comment: Lo que parece indicar eso es que ese campo es del tipo `VARCHAR` en la tabla, no del tipo `INT`.  Por eso te pone primero todos los que empiezan por `1`, luego por `2`... porque no los está tratando como números, sino como cadena.

Comment: Entonces deberás normalizar esa columna en tu tabla. Y si no tienes acceso a ella, puedes dotar a la clase `SisAlumnosMae` de un método que parsee el dato a entero y usar ese método para ordenar. Como comprenderás, no podrás ordenar una cadena como se ordenan los números. Digamos que ese método se llama `getCodeAsInteger`, entonces aplicas el lambda así: `alumnoMaeList.sort(Comparator.comparing(SisAlumnosMae::getCodeAsInteger));` o bien así: `alumnoMaeList.sort(Comparator.comparing(a -> a.getCodeAsInteger));`